# Do you stop earning reputation points for editing a post

Tags: discussion, reputation, edits

Do you stop earning reputation points for editing at a certain point?  Today I finally made it to 2000 points on StackOverflow, enough to review suggested edits.  Shortly afterwards, I edited a post, which was approved, but didn't receive the usual 2 points.

Comment: It probably is a duplicate. I just couldn't find the answer when I searched this site :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do you stop earning reputation points for editing at a certain point?

That's correct. When you reach 2000 reputation, your edits no longer require approval by other users, so you no longer earn rep for edits.

Comment: But you are still helping out the community. So why not earn rep?

Answer (score 6):

Congratulations, you have gained the [edit privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).  This privilege allows your edits to go straight through to active *without* hitting the review queue.  However, this also means that you don't get any more rep from doing edits *to posts*.  Edits to tag wikis still give reputation.

See also: [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

> Once you have earned the edit privilege, your edits are no longer peer reviewed and no reputation is given for edits.